# Wordpress multiple ajax filtering for custom post type with two taxonomies

Tags: ajax, wordpress, filtering

I need help for a custom post type archive page.

I want to build three filters for a custom post type with two taxonomies registered. The first taxonomy is hierarchical like category, the second not hierarchical like tag.

The first filter is for hierarchical taxonomy parent elements. The second filter for non  hierarchical taxonomy . The third is for  hierarchical taxonomy child elements.

I want to make the first filter( hierarchical taxonomy parent elements) feed the second(non  hierarchical taxonomy elements) and third(hierarchical taxonomy child elements), and then show results. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Have you looked into the FacetWP plugin? It does exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have a ul list with all parent elements of the first taxonomy. By clicking on a specific li element, I am calling an ajax function that changes the second filter that contains all the child elements of the parent taxonomy.

I try to find a way to make get_terms() work in functions.php so as to use it in an ajax function. I get variable $product_type_id through ajax javascript. It is a variable to store the parent taxonomy term_id, and  want to use it so as to get the children of the specific product type.

```
function getCurrentTerm($product_type_id){

    global $product_type_id;
    
    $my_products = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => ['awarded_product'],
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent' => $product_type_id ,                
        'order' => 'DESC'      
    ]);    
    
    return $my_products;
}


  function set_product_type_filter(){   
    

    $product_type_id = $_POST['product_type_id'];
    if( $_POST['product_type_id']!=''){ 
        $my_product = getCurrentTerm($product_type_id);

    $response['product_type_id'] = $_POST['product_type_id'];
    $response['product']=$my_product;
    echo  json_encode($response);

    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_die();
    }
  }

  add_action('wp_ajax_set_product_type_filter', 'set_product_type_filter');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_set_product_type_filter', 'set_product_type_filter');
```